# downloading gcov gnu utility source code?

Tags: gcc, gnu, gcov

I was looking for gcov source code that standard utility of gcc,
I searched online but I was not able to find any URL or references for downloading Gcov source code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple uses GNU source (and BSD source), however it tends to have very old versions.  If you search for...

```
gcov git repository
```

... you will find https://github.com/gcc-mirror, which says it is mirrored from `git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git`

If you want simply to browse the source, the mirror is suitable; for instance this file:

- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/gcov.cc

Comment: This link needs an update, with the name change to gcov.cc.

Answer (score 1):

When I run a Google search for "gcov source code", the first search result is: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5484/gcc/gcov.c

Looks to me that gcov is part of gcc.

Comment: I found same URL but "apple.com" is confusing me, It is real gcov (means open source ) code file.

Comment: Yes, Apple uses GNU open source utilities because Apple's iOS is based on Unix.